# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'eval'

Tags: python, model, training-data

```
import os
import time
import importlib
import json
from collections import OrderedDict
import logging
import argparse
import numpy as np
import random
import time
from  eval import plot_accuracy_epoch, plot_loss_epoch, make_heat_map
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm

import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim
import torch.utils.data
import torch.backends.cudnn
import torchvision.utils
import torch.nn.functional as F

from REPVGG_main import REPVGG
from block import fcbn, block
from dataloader import get_loader


def parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    # model config
    parser.add_argument("--block_type", type=str, default="basic", required=True)
    parser.add_argument("--depth", type=int, default=3, required=True)
    parser.add_argument("--option", type=str, default="A")

    # optim config
    parser.add_argument("--epochs", type=int, default=160)
    parser.add_argument("--batch_size", type=int, default=128)
    parser.add_argument("--base_lr", type=float, default=0.1)
    parser.add_argument("--weight_decay", type=float, default=1e-4)
    parser.add_argument("--momentum", type=float, default=0.9)
    parser.add_argument("--milestones", type=str, default="[80, 120]")
    parser.add_argument("--lr_decay", type=float, default=0.1)

    # run_config
    parser.add_argument("--device", type=str, default="cpu")
    parser.add_argument("--num_workers", type=int, default=2)

    args = parser.parse_args()

    model_config = OrderedDict(
        [
            ("multiplier", args.multiplier),
            ("depth", args.depth),
            ("blocks", args.blocks),
            ("in_channels", args.in_channels),
            ("reparametrize", args.reparametrize),
        ]
    )

    optim_config = OrderedDict(
        [
            ("epochs", args.epochs),
            ("batch_size", args.batch_size),
            ("base_lr", args.base_lr),
            ("weight_decay", args.weight_decay),
            ("momentum", args.momentum),
            ("milestones", json.loads(args.milestones)),
            ("lr_decay", args.lr_decay),
        ]
    )

    data_config = OrderedDict(
        [
            ("dataset", "EMOTION"),
        ]
    )
    run_config = OrderedDict(
        [
            ("device", args.device),
            ("num_workers", args.num_workers),
        ]
    )

    config = OrderedDict(
        [
            ("model_config", model_config),
            ("optim_config", optim_config),
            ("data_config", data_config),
            ("run_config", run_config),
        ]
    )

    return config

    config = parse_args()

    model = REPVGG(
        blocks=config["model_config"]["block"],
        multipl=config["model_config"]["multiplier"],
        in_channels=config["model_config"]["in_channels"],
        num_classes=config["model_config"]["numclasses"],
    )

    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(
        params=model.parameters(),
        lr=config["optim_config"]["base_lr"],
        weight_decay=config["optim_config"]["weight_decay"],
    )
    scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.MultiStepLR(
        optimizer,
        milestones=config["optim_config"]["milestones"],
        gamma=config["optim_config"]["lr_decay"],
    )
    criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

    def train(
        model, epochs, trainloader, testloader, device, criterion, optimizer, scheduler
    ):
        for epoch in range(epochs):
            for i, (images, labels) in enumerate(train_loader):
                start_time = time.time()
                images = images.to(device)
                labels = labels.to(device)
                outputs = model(images).to(device)
                loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
                optimizer.zero_grad()
                loss.backward()

                optimizer.step()
                if (i + 1) % 250 == 0:
                    elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
                    total_time += elapsed_time
                    print(
                        "Epoch {}, Step {} Loss: {:.4f} time : {:.4f}min".format(
                            epoch + 1, i + 1, loss.item(), total_time
                        )
                    )
            return train_losses


device = config["run_config"]["device"]

model.to(device)
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
train_loader, test_loader = get_loader(
    config["optim_config"]["batch_size"], config["run_config"]["num_workers"]
)

if config["model_config"]["reparametrize"] == False:

    train_loss = train(
        model,
        config["optim_config"]["epochs"],
        train_loader,
        test_loader,
        device,
        criterion,
        optimizer,
        scheduler,
    )

    plot_loss_epoch(train_loss)

if config["model_config"]["reparametriz"] == True:
    train_loss = train(
        model,
        config["optim_config"]["epochs"],
        train_loader,
        test_loader,
        device,
        criterion,
        optimizer,
        scheduler,
    )
    plot_loss_epoch(train_loss)
    model.reparametrize()

_, test_checker = get_loader(10000, config["run_config"]["num_workers"])
make_heat_map(model, test_checker, device)
```

---

FOR THIS CODE CURRENTLY FACING AN ERROR

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [4], in <cell line: 11>()
      9 import random
     10 import time
---> 11 from  eval import plot_accuracy_epoch, plot_loss_epoch, make_heat_map
     12 from tqdm.notebook import tqdm
     14 import torch

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'eval'
```

---

tried to install the module using
pip install eval
but it doesn't solved the issue.

```
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
FOR THIS CODE CURRENTLY FACING AN ERROR
```

---

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [4], in <cell line: 11>()
9 import random
10 import time
---> 11 from  eval import plot_accuracy_epoch, plot_loss_epoch, make_heat_map
12 from tqdm.notebook import tqdm
14 import torch

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'eval'

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
tried to install the module using 
pip install eval
but it doesn't solved the issue.
```

Comment: The module `eval` does not exist, nor do the functions inside. If you manually wrote this module, make sure it is in the same directory as your `main.py` file.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a module from your source code is missing rather than a missing external module. So you won't be able to pip install that one.

I'd check if there's an "eval" file or folder defining those functions being imported. If the file is there, you probably need to make sure that you are executing the code from the right location. If the file is not there, your codebase might be incomplete.

Comment: Adding on, calling a module `eval` (which is a python builtin), should be avoided.